# How to handle slider change event for multiple sliders in a page: JqueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In my app i have multiple pages in a single HTML template, each of this pages have 5 sliders, 
when i move the slider ,based on the value(1 to 5) i will display a text.
Below i sample of two pages

```
<!-- Start of 2 page--> 
<div data-role="page" id="page2" >
     <!-- Start of content -->
    <div data-role="content" id="target-content">

   <label for="slider">1. .............</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

     <label for="slider1">2............................ </label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

     <label for="slider2">3. ................</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

    </div>
    <!-- end of content -->

</div>
<!-- end of 2 page-->

<!-- Start of 3 page--> 
<div data-role="page" id="page3" >
     <!-- Start of content -->
    <div data-role="content" id="target-content"" >

   <label for="slider">1. .............</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

     <label for="slider1">2............................ </label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

     <label for="slider2">3. ................</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel"></label>

    </div>
    <!-- end of content --> 
</div>
<!-- end of 3 page-->
```

i am doing for the first slider based on the id as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {

    $("#slider").change(function () {
        sVal = $(this).val();

        if (sVal == 0) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('');
        }

        if (sVal == 1) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('Strongly disagree');
        }

          if (sVal == 2) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('Disagree');
        }

          if (sVal == 3) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('Neither agree nor disagree');
        }

          if (sVal == 4) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('Agree');
        }

          if (sVal == 5) {
            $('#sliderlabel').text('Strongly Agree');
        }   

    });
});
</script>
```

Now how to implement changing the text for each sliders of the page and also sliders of all other pages which are in one single index.html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Raymond Camden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52160/raymond-camden) mentioned in his answer, use `.class` instead of `id`, as `id` should be unique.

Since you're using *Multi-Page Model*, you need to add `change` listener upon `pagecreate` event. However, you have to specify which page in order not to add *multiple* listener on same page (usually first page in DOM). On `pagecreate` add `change` listeners to `.slider` that are within `$(event.target)` page, this way.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (event) {
   $(event.target).find(".slider").on("change", function () {
      sVal = $(this).val();
        if (sVal == 1) {
          $(this).closest("div").next('.sliderlabel').text('New text');
        }
   });
});
```

`$(event.target)` is the page that has been created, using `.find()`, attach `change` listener to `.slider`.

To change *label*'s text, you also need to replace `id` with `.class`. Moreover, you need to use `.closest()` and `.next()` since *sliders* are wrapped in `<div class="ui-slider">` and *label* is a sibling of that div.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3RNA7/)**

Comment: hi i am facing few issues unfortunately i am unable to make the header and footer toggle free(fade in/out). does not related to this question  though

Comment: @teekib have posted a question in that regard?

Comment: yes..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318809/jquerymobile-phonegap-tap-toggle-slider-footer-issues

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector from an ID based one (#something) to a class based one (.something). Then change your code to get sliderlabel to be more generic using jQuery sibling type selectors. So for example, it looks like the label is always the next item from the slider. The next() api (http://api.jquery.com/next/) should do it.